# Loops running time as function of n

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Suppose I have the following code and I'd like to compute running time as function of $\ n$:

```
sum = 0
i = n
while i >= 1:
    y = 1
    while y < i:
         y = y * 2
    i = i-1
```

I think the y loop is running from $\ 1 $ to $\ \lceil \log_2(i) \rceil +1 $ and the outsider loop is from $\ n $ to $\ 1 $ so it should be something as:

$$\ \sum_{i=1}^n \lceil \log_2(i) \rceil + 1$$

Not sure if correct and if it is how do I show it as function of n?

Comment: That formula *is* a function of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the inner loop executes $\lceil\log_2(i)\rceil$ times because it iterates as long as  `y < i`. Hence you have $T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lceil\log_2(i)\rceil$. Note that $ \lceil\log_2(i)\rceil \le \log_2(i) + 1$, therefore:

$T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lceil\log_2(i)\rceil \le \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \log_2\left(i\right) + 1\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log_2(i) + n$

Now, $\sum_{i=1}^n \log_2(i) = \log_2(1) + \log_2(2) + ... + \log_2(n) = \log_2(n!)$ .

Finally you have $T(n) \le \log_2(n!) + n$, which is $O(n \log n)$ see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Thanks! but if $\ i = 7 $ then $\ y $ iterates $\ 1, 2, 4, 8 $ so it should be $\ \lceil \log i \rceil + 1 $ no?

Answer (score 1):

An exact solution is possible.

Assuming that $n=2^m$, an exact power of $2$, the number of executions of the inner loop equals

$$0+1+2+2+3+3+3+3+\cdots \underbrace{m+m+\cdots m}_{2^{m-1}}$$
or

$$T:=\sum_{i=0}^mi\,2^{i-1}.$$

Now

$$2T:=2\sum_{i=0}^mi\,2^{i-1}=2\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}(i-1)2^{i-2}=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}(i-1)2^{i-1}=\frac12+\sum_{i=0}^{m}(i-1)2^{i-1}+m\,2^m$$ and finally

$$T=\frac12-\frac{2^{m+1}-1}2+m\,2^m=(m-1)2^m+1=mn-n+1.$$

---

Now if $n$ is not a power of $2$, consider $m=\lfloor\lg n\rfloor$ and the count is

$$0+1+2+2+3+3+3+3+\cdots \underbrace{m+1+m+1+\cdots m+1}_{n-2^{m-1}}.$$

Then

$$T= (m-1)2^m+1+(m+1)(n-2^{m-1})=mn+n-2\cdot2^{m}+1.$$

---

$\Theta(n\log n)$.